# Sum of rows that a match a condition in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this large dataframe in which I recurrently have duplicated events, one of which has a timestamp of zero:

```
a     b     c 
139 4E+08 0.234
163 6E+08 0.964
163     0 0.034
172 6E+08 1.173
183 6E+08 0.734`
183     0 0.296
```

and so on.
What I would like to do is to sum every rows that satisfy the condition timestamp=0 to the previous one, to have something like this:

```
a     b     c
139 4E+08 0.234
163 6E+08 0.998
172 6E+08 1.173
183 6E+08 1.030
```

I looked at various solutions but can find the proper one... how could I solve this? thanks

Comment: check out [pd.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer assumes that your rows which have `0` values for `b` are going to have same `a` value as its previous row. Since you have not explicitly stated this, so here is my answer that generalize without any assumptions.

Using [`pandas.apply`](/link) to add the `0` values to each of the previous row in main dataframe.

```
data_dict = {'a' : [139,163,163,172,183,183], 'b' : [float(4e08), float(6e08), 0, float(6e08), float(6e08), 0], 'c' : [0.234,0.964,0.034,1.173,0.734,0.296]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

mask = df['b'].eq(0)

def adder(row):
    if row.name:
        df.loc[row.name-1, 'c'] += row['c']

    
_ = df[df['b'].eq(0)].apply(adder, axis=1)
df = df[~mask]
```

which gives us the expected output

```
df
     a            b      c
0  139  400000000.0  0.234
1  163  600000000.0  0.998
3  172  600000000.0  1.173
4  183  600000000.0  1.030
```

##### Alternatively

Here is another solution using [`pandas.dataframe.assign`](/link) and [`pandas.dataframe.loc`](/link).

```
df = df.assign(b_t = df['b'].shift(-1), c_t = df['c'].shift(-1) )
mask = df['b_t'].eq(0)
df[mask].loc[:,'c'] += df[mask].loc[:,'c_t']
df = df[~df['b'].eq(0)]
```

which gives us the same output :

```
df
     a            b      c
0  139  400000000.0  0.234
1  163  600000000.0  0.964
3  172  600000000.0  1.173
4  183  600000000.0  0.734
```

##### Don't want another mask

If you don't want to create another mask, you can use the same mask as well.

```
df = df.assign(b_t = df['b'].shift(-1), c_t = df['c'].shift(-1) )
mask = df['b_t'].eq(0)
df[mask].loc[:,'c'] += df[mask].loc[:,'c_t']
mask = mask.shift(1).fillna(False)
df.mask(mask, inplace=True)
df = df.dropna().drop(['b_t', 'c_t'], axis = 1)
```

which gives us

```
       a            b      c
0  139.0  400000000.0  0.234
1  163.0  600000000.0  0.964
3  172.0  600000000.0  1.173
4  183.0  600000000.0  0.734
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to do, you could group by the values in column `a` and `sum` the values on each of the other columns. Then reset the index to get column `a` back.

```
df.groupby('a').sum().reset_index()
```

Kudos to @ouyang-ze for the suggestion.

Comment: I also managed to work with this solution. thank you!